# How does one go about debugging databinding issues in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, mvvm

I have rebuilt [Josh Smith's CommandSink example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VMCommanding.aspx) from scratch and my version runs without error *except* that my command buttons are grayed out. I assume this is because there is something somewhere not set correctly so that the commands never get set to `CanExecute = true` or at some point get set to `CanExecute = false`.

But since the databinding is essentially going on in the XAML, I am not sure where to "set a breakpoint on the command" so I can see at what time a button is assigned CanExecute = false or e.g. is NOT assigned `CanExecute = true`.

Essentially I have these command bindings in a view:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <sink:CommandSinkBinding Command="vm:CustomerViewModel.CloseCommand"/>
    <sink:CommandSinkBinding Command="vm:CustomerViewModel.ShowInformationCommand"/>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

and in my CustomerViewModel the command is defined like this:

```
public static readonly RoutedCommand CloseCommand = new RoutedCommand();

public bool CanBeClosed
{
    get { return _customer.IsOpen; }
}

public void Close()
{
    _customer.IsOpen = false;

    this.OnPropertyChanged("CanBeClosed");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("CanBeApproved");
}
```

But since my understanding of MVVM right now is that you set up your M-VM-M, run your application and things "get data bound and just work".

**I guess I am looking for something like a "Page Cycle" as in ASP.NET** in which to step through to find out when my commands are `CanExecute = true` and when they are `CanExecute = false`.

How could one go about debugging an WPF/MVVM pattern like this where the databinding is not done explicitly in the code, and hence one cannot step-through debug in the classic sense?

## Answer:

Although [this article that Gishu mentioned](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52) was helpful in general regarding how to go about debugging databinding issues, and generally answered my question on how to do just that, it didn't help me in my particular case.

For what it's worth, I figured my particular issue with this code out by doing a line-per-line comparison with Josh Smith's original code and found these two lines that were missing from the `CommandSinkBinding.OnCommandSinkChanged` method:

```
if (!ConfigureDelayedProcessing(depObj, commandSink))
    ProcessCommandSinkChanged(depObj, commandSink);
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate (atleast in terms of the answer)? of
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337023/how-to-detect-broken-wpf-data-binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337023/how-to-detect-broken-wpf-data-binding) You could also google for Bea Stollnitz article on the same.

Comment: The link in the answer part is dead now :(

Answer (score 0):

First point:

To debug XAML Binding you can add reference to Diagnostics from WindowsBase dll to the XAML file, 
then when binding to some property add PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel. When you run it check out the output window.

XAML sample :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding someProperty, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
```

Second point:

your command being grayed out means that your binding works! What doesn't happen is that the command doesn't refresh it's state, meaning CanExe() method ran and set the command to "can't exe state", however it never does check again if it can toggle its state back to "can exe". There are many ways to do it, but basically when a certain property changes in your ViewModel, refresh your command state:

in Prism, for example you can call someCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged ();

Comment: This example is missing some guidance about what to do after adding the diagnostics properties