# How can I debug the binding of my ViewModels to my View?

Tags: wpf, debugging, mvvm, binding, observablecollection

I have this ItemsControl in my **View**:

```
<ItemsControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemPageItemViewModels}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemPageItemViewModelsTemplate}"/>
```

And above it I have this DataTemplate which renders all the items:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemPageItemViewModelsTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem is that although there are 8 objects in the **ItemPageItemViewModels** ObservableCollection in my **ViewModel**, only the ***last* object is being displayed on the screen *8 times***.

I can set a breakpoint in my ViewModel to see that there are indeed 8 different objects in the ObserverableCollection, but **how can I *debug the binding* to see why this DataTemplate is rendering the last object in the collection 8 times upon my screen?**

Comment: Have you seen this topic?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337023/how-to-detect-broken-wpf-data-binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Bea Stollnitz's excellent article about this.

- [How can I debug WPF bindings?](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52)