# Troubleshooting WPF / Silverlight XAML databinding?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

Whenever I am doing XAML, I tend to run into problems with databinding. It is often small issues, such as misspelling a property name.

My problem is, that I don't seem to receive any errors or warnings when I am trying to bind to a property that does not exist. It would be nice to get a warning, either at compile or runtime, about my errors.

Is it possible to get a warning about wrong databinding expressions ? What do you do to troubleshoot when your data does not appear as expected ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect broken WPF Data binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337023/how-to-detect-broken-wpf-data-binding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF will write warnings about problems in data binding to the Visual Studio "Output" window

Comment: You are very right. Many people dont use that "Output" window at all. Its the best source of information to find out if anything has gone wrong!! Cheers !!

Comment: The Output window doesn't appear write a warning if something on the binding path is null. That was my actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post, [How can I debug WPF bindings?](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52) helped me learn why my Binding was failing.

I've accepted the other answer to this question because it is technically correct, but I wanted to include the link above in this question, for future reference.