# Broken binding without error

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have simple WPF application with two windows and I want to change it to use the MVVM model.

I started creating a simple binding with a button and a messagebox, but it doesn't work. The Execute function of my command is never called, but I get no binding error in the output window.

I debug and trace the binding using these:
http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52
[How to detect broken WPF Data binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337023/how-to-detect-broken-wpf-data-binding)

The trace is the following:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 54 : Created BindingExpression (hash=8493835) for Binding (hash=45202970)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 :   Path: 'LoginCommand'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 59 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.Button.Command (hash=17604022)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 68 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): Found data context element: Button (hash=17604022) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): Activate with root item LoginViewModel (hash=47369058)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835):   At level 0 - for LoginViewModel.LoginCommand found accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(LoginCommand)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): Replace item at level 0 with LoginViewModel (hash=47369058), using accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(LoginCommand)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 99 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): GetValue at level 0 from LoginViewModel (hash=47369058) using ReflectPropertyDescriptor(LoginCommand): RelayCommand (hash=32714449)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): TransferValue - got raw value RelayCommand (hash=32714449)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 82 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): TransferValue - implicit converter produced <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 87 : BindingExpression (hash=8493835): TransferValue - using final value <null>
```

The relevant parts of my code are below.

Loginview.xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:LoginViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

...

```
<Button Content="Login"
        Command="{Binding LoginCommand, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
        CommandParameter="Hello">
```

LoginViewModel.cs:

```
class LoginViewModel
{
    private RelayCommand m_LoginCommand;
    public RelayCommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_LoginCommand == null) 
            {
                m_LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Login(param));
            }
            return m_LoginCommand;
        }
    }

    public void Login(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());
    }
}
```

RelayCommand.cs:

```
class RelayCommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // breakpoint; code execution never reaches here
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I assume all your classes are "public" in your code?

Comment: Nope... they have the default visibility.
I've tried this tutorial (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute) in a different project and it works.

Comment: Is this the actual code? It won't compile, this line is wrong: MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RelayCommand` is a plain class, it is not implementing `ICommand`. This will work:

```
class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // breakpoint; code execution never reaches here
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem! Thanks, such a lame error!

What I still don't get however are the trace messages...
TransferValue - implicit converter produced <null> is so meaningless.