# change the datatemplate for the rowdetails of a datagrid based on row value

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatemplate

I have a wpf application using MVVM principles.  Within this application I have a datagrid where I want to have each row choose between one of 6 possible datatemplates based on the value of an underlying property in the object bound to the datagrid row.

**GOAL:**
I do not want to use code behind and want to avoid using a datatemplateselector.  I would like to use a datatrigger to select from different data templates for the DetailsTemplate of each row.

**ATTEMPTED:**
I tried to define a datatrigger within the DataGrid as follows, but it does not work.

```
            <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" MinHeight="300"          
                    ItemsSource="{Binding TrackingCollection}"  
                    CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                    SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTracking, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding tracking_action.chrCode}" Value="RC">
                            <!-- RECIEVING -->
                            <Setter Property="DetailsTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FTC_TrackingReceivingDetailTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding tracking_action.chrCode}" Value="SH">
                            <!-- SHIPPING -->
                            <Setter Property="DetailsTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FTC_TrackingShippingDetailTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding tracking_action.chrCode}" Value="ST">
                            <!-- STOCKING -->
                            <Setter Property="DetailsTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FTC_TrackingStockingDetailTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding tracking_action.chrCode}" Value="OR">
                            <!-- ORDERING -->
                            <Setter Property="DetailsTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FTC_TrackingOrderingDetailTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding tracking_action.chrCode}" Value="RT">
                            <!-- RETURNING -->
                            <Setter Property="DetailsTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FTC_TrackingReturningDetailTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding tracking_action.chrCode}" Value="TR">
                            <!-- TRANSFERING -->
                            <Setter Property="DetailsTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FTC_TrackingTransferingDetailTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                   ''column definitions go here
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

**ERROR:**
When I run the app I get the following error:

> 'Add value to collection of type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.' Line
>   number '137' and line position '35'.

This error goes away if I remove the Style tag/content from the datagrid definition above.

Can someone please help me define the row's datatemplate based on the value of a property within that row.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put Style into `<DataGrid.Resources>` under `<DataGrid>`, not directly under `<DataGrid>`.

Comment: awesome, moved the style inside of a datagrid.resources and everything works exactly as I want.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Stipo, The datatemplate does not change when I select a different vlaue in the combobox that binds to the object property tracking_action.chrCode as shown above.  Do you know why?

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work, you should try to debug it. Try with suggestions from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337023/how-to-detect-broken-wpf-data-binding