# WPF datagrid not binding to a simple query

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

This is my code . I am simply trying to select all students in my Students table ( which has 5 records, all visible in the Server Explorer )

```
var students = from p in schoolEntities.students
               select p;

               myGrid.DataContext = students.ToList();
```

This is my XAML for datagrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="myGrid  /> // alignment etc left out
```

But this is what I am getting

[image]

I'm sure it is something trivial that I am leaving out above because binding the same DataGrid to , say a list of a class **Person** works fine, but using Linq for my database isn't working.

UPDATE:
( I hope below is clear) 
I just discovered that the Students table that has two columns Id and Name has a many to many relationship with Subjects table , which has id and SubjectName and there is a StudentsSubjects table with two columns StudentId, SubjectId which makes the many to many relationship work.

That is the cause of the problem. If I bind this datagrid to a simple **Teachers**table it works because teachers table has no relationships.

Now I understand the problem, but I still don't know how to fix it :(

Thank you

Comment: DataContext takes an IEnumerable, so ToList is actually not necessary, but may not be the issue here

Comment: @Samuel not using Tolist throws "Direct binding to query is not supported exception" The problem is being caused by the Many to Many relationship of Students table... still I don't know how to fix that :(

Comment: Furthermore it looks ok, try a manual IEnumerable object for the grid as I do not see any issues. For broken Bindings you can check the logs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337023/how-to-detect-broken-wpf-data-binding

Comment: I see, if such many to many relation creates a circular reference then it should be an issue to display it here. You probably want to create a custom data template for Person that handles the reference to other Persons gracefully

Comment: OK, I managed to fix it by doing a join ( duh to myself) with this linq to sql join query  'var students = from t1 in schoolEntities.Students
                           join t2 in schoolEntities.Subjects on t1.Id equals t2.Id
                           select t1;

            myGrid.ItemsSource = students.ToList();'