# C# WPF Application runs on the developed Computer but not any where else

Tags: c#, wpf, crash

I developed an application in C# while debugging and building The visual studio shows no error and build it. in my own computer it works fine and there is no problem but when I try it in another computer with windows 7 & 8 it is crashing, in windows XP nothing happens. I collect these information from the app crash windows of windows 7. this app developed in .NETFramework 4.

> Description:
>     Stopped working
>
> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name:    CLR20r3
>
> Problem Signature 01:    V21F5CYJZFDVI34WYCI1RF00F1LB4LLE
>
> Problem Signature 02: 1.1.0.0
>
> Problem Signature 03: 53d41ada
>
> Problem Signature 04: PresentationFramework
>
> Problem Signature 05: 3.0.0.0
>
> Problem Signature 06: 4ca2e335
>
> Problem Signature 07: 625d
>
> Problem Signature 08: e1
>
> Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
>
> OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>
> Locale ID:    1033

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think i remember seeing this problem when I needed to update my framework. What framework did you develop your app in and what .net framework is installed on the computers you are trying to run the programs on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error line

> Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse

indicates that there is an issue with your XAML. Maybe you are referencing an image file that isn't there, or something like that.

It's useful to override the `OnAppDispatcherUnhandledException` method of the Application to get error messages out more clearly. Also, take a look at this question: [How to detect broken WPF Data binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337023/how-to-detect-broken-wpf-data-binding).