# Binding TextBlock Text to Window Title doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am manually creating a TextBlock and binding it's Text property to the Title property of the window by typing in the XAML file and when I compile and run the application, the TextBlock does not contain any text.  Here is the code I am entering in to the MainWindow.xaml file:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=window}"/>
```

However, if I use the "Create Data Binding..." option from the property window on the right hand side of Visual Studio 2013 and it puts the exact same code in but when I compile and run the program it works...

I know I can just do this to get it to work but I have a bunch of code that I like to copy and paste and if I do this in this situation it doesn't work.

This seems to be the only property that does this on the window because I can bind to the window's Icon, Background, and Foreground properties without issue.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or is this a bug in VS2013?

** **MORE INFORMATION FOR FUTURE REFERENCE** **

Apparently when you use the "Create Data Binding..." option from the Properties window it automatically adds `x:Name="window"` to the code for the Window control.  This explains why it works when using the menu and not when typing it in.

Comment: I have seen something like that myself

Comment: Use the suggestions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337023/how-to-detect-broken-wpf-data-binding to debug the first binding that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ElementName` is just that: the name of the element. Try setting it in parent window itself with `x:Name="window'"`.

Answer (score 0):

set the name and refer to the name
not making it up - I do this
but I have not tested Title

```
<Window ... 
        x:Name="_this"
```