# Page does not update when a property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have Page that contains a button, whose Datacontext is taken from a static resource in this code:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="DataContext" ObjectType="{x:Type modelview:ProductionPageModelView}"/>
<Button Content="Save" DataContext="{StaticResource DataContext}" IsEnabled="{Binding HasPandingChanges,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWay,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
        Command="{Binding ModifyProduction}" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

This resource linked to `ModelView` and the `IsPandingChanges` property is in the base class of `ProductionPageModelView`, (you can say the `BaseModelView` class).

And I have in the view model class:

```
public static Dictionary<object, OpertationType> ChangeTracker { get; } = new Dictionary<object, OpertationType>();

public bool HasPandingChanges => ChangeTracker.Count > 0;
```

when I add an item to *ChangeTracker* Dictionary, nothing changes and in debug, it shows that it returns true.

I tried to put `OnPropertyChanged` in every `ChangeTracker.Add` method implementation

```
public virtual object AddData()
{
    DataTransactionType = OpertationType.Insert;
    if (ChangeTracker.ContainsKey(this))
    {
        ChangeTracker[this] = DataTransactionType;
    }
    else
        ChangeTracker.Add(this, DataTransactionType);

    OnPropertyChange(nameof(HasPandingChanges));
    return null;
}
```

`OnProeprtyChanged Method`

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string Propertyname = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Propertyname));
}
```

When I call `AddData`. Nothing changed even `HasPandingChanges` returns true.

Comment: I will suggest you to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337023/how-to-detect-broken-wpf-data-binding). You will find that useful when something doesn't work in WPF.

Comment: Also, why are you using `DataContext="{StaticResource DataContext}"`? What's that `DataContext` you are passing in?

Comment: @Camilo thank you for your time. I've updated my question. hope it made it more clear now.

Comment: Give a look at https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: @Tony I'm using Fody PropertyCahnged library, only this property does not update so I put OnPropertyChanged in my code manually.